# ConnectionState changes twice in main class

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have this app where I have an intro screen that I want to hide if the user has already skipped once.
I'm using bloc with a Provider.
My issue is the connection state changes twice when I hot restart the app and I've been spending hours without understanding the reason.

Here is my code:

my main class

```
void main() => runApp(StatsApp());

class StatsApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => IntroProvider(),
        )
      ],
      child: Consumer<IntroProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: FutureBuilder(
          future: value.bloc.checkSkipped(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.connectionState);
            print(snapshot.data);
            return SplashScreen();
          },
        ));
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

my bloc

```
enum IntroEvents {
  ReadLocalStorage,
  SetIntroSkipped,
}

class IntroBloc extends Bloc<IntroEvents, bool> {
  PrefsManager _prefsManager = PrefsManager.instance;

  Future<bool> checkSkipped() async {
    this.add(IntroEvents.ReadLocalStorage);
    final skipped =
        await _prefsManager.getValue(PrefTypes.Bool, "skippedIntro");
    return skipped;
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement initialState
  bool get initialState => false;

  @override
  Stream<bool> mapEventToState(IntroEvents event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case IntroEvents.SetIntroSkipped:
        _prefsManager.setValue(PrefTypes.Bool, "skippedIntro", true);
        yield true;
        break;
      case IntroEvents.ReadLocalStorage:
        final skipped =
            await _prefsManager.getValue(PrefTypes.Bool, "skippedIntro");
        yield skipped;
        break;
      default:
        print("wtffffff");
    }
  }
}
```

my provider

```
class IntroProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  IntroBloc _bloc;

  IntroProvider(){
    print("called IntroProvider");
    _bloc = IntroBloc();
  }

  IntroBloc get bloc => _bloc;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When working with snapshots you're able to check whether the `snapshot.hasData`. Normally you'd wrap the functionality you want to run when the snapshot has data in an `if` statement and provide some kind of default `Widget` when it does not.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: value.bloc.checkSkipped(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.connectionState);

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      print(snapshot.data);
    }

    return SplashScreen();
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I still see the prints displaying several time but I guess it has something to do with the asynchronous nature. 
But at least now I don't see the SplashScreen appearing then disappearing.
Do you have any good resource to recommand where I can lear how to combine Provider with Block? I've spent some amount of time watching youtube videos but most of the examples are very simple.
Cheers

Comment: Normally you use one or the other, not both. I've seen get_it be used with either provider or block but never both of them be used together.